# Rendering Flask JSON response in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

So, I've been struggling with this and couldn't really find a solution. I have a Flask backend that does some operations and returns a JSON response like so

server.py

```
from flask import Flask
from pyresparser import ResumeParser


app = Flask(__name__)

# Details API Route
@app.route("/details")
def details():
    resume_data = ResumeParser(r'D:\React\Candetect\backend\Uploaded_Resumes\OmkarResume.pdf').get_extracted_data()
    email = resume_data.get('email')    
    return {"Information":[email]}

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, I'm getting this JSON response in App.jsx like so

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetch("/details").then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
setData([data.Information])
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  }, [])
```

And I'm trying to display it like so

```
<div>
      {(data.length === 0) ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        data.members.map((member, i) => (
          <h3 key={i}>{member.email}</h3>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
    </div>
```

The problem, the page loads up, I get loading... message displayed, then as the data is fetched I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

For some reason it's considering it to be undefined.

This is what I get when I console.log(data)

```
{
    "Information": [
        "omkarpathak27@gmail.com"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's `.members`, and `member[i].email`? I don't see it in your response, which only has `.Information`, and each element in `.Information` is a string. If you `console.log(data)`, you should see `[["omkarpathak27@gmail.com"]]` which is probably not the structure you want, but can be rendered with `<div>{data[0][0]}</div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Effects let you run some code after rendering so that you can synchronize your component with some system outside of React*

So basically, when your code will run for the first time, the code inside useEffect won't run. Using something like this, you can have a fallback render until your data loads.

```
    if (!data) {
return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }
```

A better solution would be to have a loading state that keeps track of the data that is being loaded.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/details")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setData([data.Information]);
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(data);
        });
}, []);

if (loading && !data) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
}

if (!loading && !data) {
    return <p>Opps. Something`s wrong</p>;
}

return (
    <div>
        {data.members.map((member, i) => (
            <h3 key={i}>{member.email}</h3>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

### React v18 Fix

If you have the problem of useEffect firing twice, you can use something like to prevent it from doing that.

```
function App() {
  const effectRan = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (effectRan.current === true || process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
      //
      //Code that should only run once !
      //
    }
    return () => (effectRan.current = true);
  }, []);

  return <p></p>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `data = []` will always be truthy, so `!data` is pointless. OP already has a guard, `data.length === 0` to avoid calling `.members` on an empty array. If you look at OP's structure, there are no `.members` or `.email` keys, which probably explains their error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`. Nothing here addresses that.

Comment: I found the fix guys. I'm answering right now

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up switching my code a bit. Here's what I did instead:

App.jsx

```
const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState([{}])

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/details').then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => setInitialData(data))
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        <h3>Hello {initialData.name}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Then, in server.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Details API Route
@app.route("/details")
def details():
    data = func(r'path\to\pdf').get_data()
    return {"email":data.get('email'),
            "mobile_number":data.get('mobile_number'),
            "name":data.get('name'),
    }

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```